# ERROR: The property or indexer "CharacterStats.currentHealth" cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a food / water system, so when you are 0 on food or water you will loose some health, this shall go even faster when you are 0 on both. But i keep getting this Error "ERROR: The property or indexer "CharacterStats.currentHealth" cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible." Here is my scripts can you guys help me, down below is my scripts.

```
public class PlayerStats : CharacterStats
{
    public string ID{get;protected set;}
    public Texture healthIcon;
    public Texture waterIcon;
    public Texture foodIcon;
    public float water = 100;
    public float food = 100;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        EquipmentManager.instance.onEquipmentChanged += OnEquipmentChanged;
    }

    void OnEquipmentChanged(Equipment newItem, Equipment oldItem)
    {
        if (newItem != null)
        {
            armor.AddModifier(newItem.armorModifier);
            damage.AddModifier(newItem.damageModifier);
        }

        if (oldItem != null)
        {
            armor.RemoveModifier(oldItem.armorModifier);
            damage.RemoveModifier(oldItem.damageModifier);
        }
    }

    public override void Die()
    {
        base.Die();
        //Kill the player in some way
        PlayerManager.instance.KillPlayer();
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        //GUIStyle style = "box";

        GUIStyle style = "box";
        var healthstring = currentHealth.ToString("0");
        var waterstring = water.ToString("0");
        var foodstring = food.ToString("0");

        //Health
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), healthstring, style);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(15, 12, 100 / 4, 25), healthIcon, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, true, 10f);
        //Water
        GUI.Label(new Rect(240, 10, 100, 30), waterstring, style);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(245, 12, 100 / 4, 25), waterIcon, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, true, 10f);
        //Food
        GUI.Label(new Rect(355, 10, 100, 30), foodstring, style);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(360, 12, 100 / 4, 25), foodIcon, ScaleMode.StretchToFill, true, 10f);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
       if(water <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Losing food");
            currentHealth = currentHealth - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

2nd-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public class CharacterStats : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public float currentHealth { get; private set; }

    public Stat damage;
    public Stat armor;

    void Awake()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        damage -= armor.GetValue();
        damage = Mathf.Clamp(damage, 0, int.MaxValue);


        currentHealth -= damage;
        Debug.Log(transform.name + " takes " + damage + " damage");

        if(currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    public virtual void Die()
    {
        Debug.Log(transform.name + " died.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh...have you considered not making the set accessor `private` for `currentHealth`?

Comment: `public float currentHealth { get; private set; }` should be `public float currentHealth { get; protected set; }` if you want derived classes to have the ability to modify it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels

Comment: I am new to coding and c# so i if an error like that pops up ill often wont know how to solve it, so thanks to you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you have a `private set`.  The problem with a private set is that the value can only be changed in the containing type `CharacterStats` and not derived types `PlayerStats`.

```
public class CharacterStats
{
    public float Health {get; private set;}
    public float HealthA2 {get; set;}

    public CharacterStats()
    {
        Health = 100;//I can change the value in the constructor.  Making this immutable
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Health = 75;//I can again change the value after construction so immutable not so much after all
    }
}

public class PlayerStats : CharacterStats
{
    public void MoreWork()
    {
        HealthA2 = 50;//This works
        //Health = 50;//ERROR:  I cannot change a private set in the derived class.  For that I need at least protected set;
    }
}
```

See also [Immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).  And [accessibility levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels).

Comment: Thank you! While i have you here, can i ask another question? "GUI.Label(new Rect(355, 10, 100, 30), foodstring, style);" if i want this centered should i just use Screen.height / 2 and half the size of the box and the same for the width or is there an easier solution?

Comment: @OlavAuslandOnstad - There are plenty of excellent experts on SO.  Post a new question and a bunch of people will be happy to help.